# How to get more parallelism out of spark in kubernetes without increasing physical cores?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am running spark jobs on GKE Autopilot (Google's kubernetes engine). My workload is not very CPU intensive so CPU is idle a lot.

In spark-submit, I use `spark.executor.cores` and `spark.executor.instances` and GKE provisions appropriately sized nodes and starts executor pods based on this config.

However, there is 1:1 correlation between kubernetes pod core and spark task core. So, spark parallelism is limited to `spark.executor.cores * spark.executor.instances`. This causes very low CPU utilization and thus high cost of running.

In spark local mode, I can give more cores than are physically present and it is upto the OS to schedule and run the threads in parallel. In spark standalone mode, there is `SPARK_WORKER_CORES` which can also overcommit CPU.

There is `spark.task.cpus` which does the opposite of what I want.

Is there a way to overcommit cores when running in kubernetes?